# Scrapy How to Duplicate Content

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to **scrape** reviews of multiple hotels in Tripadvisor and I was able to **scrape** data with 150 observations which consists of 150 reviews data from 30 hotels.

However when I try to add new column of hotel_name and perform crawl, the hotel name doesn't reoccur and the number of observations is decreased to the number of hotels which is 30. How can I make the hotel name duplicated to each of the review row?

This is the code I'm using:

```
    import scrapy
from..items import ReviewItem
import re


class TripAdvisorReview(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tripadvisor"
    start_urls = ["https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotels-g186217-England-Hotels.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("div.listing_title a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

    def parse_hotel(self, response):
        for info in response.css('div.page'):
            items = ReviewItem()
            hotel_names = info.css('._1mTlpMC3::text').extract()
            hotel_names = [hotel_name.strip() for hotel_name in hotel_names]
            reviewer_names = info.css('._1r_My98y::text').extract()
            reviewer_names = [reviewer_name.strip() for reviewer_name in reviewer_names]
            reviewer_contributions = info.css('._3fPsSAYi:nth-child(1) ._1fk70GUn , ._1TuWwpYf+ ._3fPsSAYi ._1fk70GUn').css('::text').extract()
            reviewer_contributions = [reviewer_contribution.strip() for reviewer_contribution in reviewer_contributions]
            review_dates = info.xpath('//div[@class = "_2fxQ4TOx"]/span[contains(text(),"wrote a review")]/text()').extract()
            review_dates = [review_date.strip() for review_date in review_dates]
            review_stars = info.css('div.nf9vGX55 .ui_bubble_rating').xpath("@class").extract()
            review_stars = [review_star.strip() for review_star in review_stars]
            review_texts = info.css('#component_15 .cPQsENeY').css('::text').extract()
            review_texts = [review_text.strip() for review_text in review_texts]
            #helpful_vote = info.css('._3kbymg8R::text').extract()
            result = zip(hotel_names, reviewer_names, review_dates, review_texts, review_stars, reviewer_contributions)

        for hotel_name, reviewer_name, review_date, review_text, review_star, reviewer_contribution in result:
            items['hotel_name'] = hotel_name
            items['reviewer_name'] = reviewer_name
            items['reviewer_contribution'] = reviewer_contribution
            items['review_date'] = review_date
            items['review_star'] = review_star
            items['review_text'] = review_text
            #items['helpful_vote'] = helpful_vote
            yield items
```

Comment: if you expect more items in `for`-loop then you should create list for results, not `result` which can keep only single result. OR you should use second `for`-loop inside first `for`-loop. Simply you have wrong indentations.

Comment: BTW: sometimes searching elements separatelly and later join them with `zip()` may gives wrong results. When one item doesn't have ie. `stars` then it will not put `None` in this place but it will move `stars` from next element in this place.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - especially in `result` before scond `for`-loop - it will use only last `result` from first `for`-loop.

Comment: problem can be also `zip()`. Your `hotel_names` has only one value but other variables like `reviewer_names` has 5 values - but `zip()` will use shortest list so it will create only one item. You should use `zip()` without `hotel_names` and later add this name manually to every `item['hotel_name'] `

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `hotel_names` has only one value but other elements has five values - check:

```
        print('hotel_names:', len(hotel_names))
        print('reviewer_names:', len(reviewer_names))
        print('review_dates:', len(review_dates))
        print('review_stars:', len(review_stars))
        print('review_texts:', len(review_texts))
        print('reviewer_contributions:', len(reviewer_contributions))
```

but `zip()` uses length of shortest list to create items - so it creates only one itme.

You should use `zip()` without `hotel_names` and later add `hotel_names[0]` to every item.

```
# without `hotel_names`
all_reviews = zip(reviewer_names, review_dates, review_texts, review_stars, reviewer_contributions)

hotel_name = hotel_names[0]  # <-- manually get first hotel

# without `hotel_name`
for reviewer_name, review_date, review_text, review_star, reviewer_contribution in all_reviews:
    #items = ReviewItem()
    items = dict()
    items['hotel_name'] = hotel_name  # <-- manually add first hotel
    items['reviewer_name'] = reviewer_name
    items['reviewer_contribution'] = reviewer_contribution
    items['review_date'] = review_date
    items['review_star'] = review_star
    items['review_text'] = review_text
    #items['helpful_vote'] = helpful_vote
    yield items
```

---

**BTW:** There is also other problem - `review_texts` often has more then 5 items (ie. 11 items) and it means you use wrong method to get this text.

When I check CSV then I see it treads `...` as separated review. You have to change it.

---

Minimal working code.

You can put all code in one file and run it without creating project - `python script.py`. This way everyone can test it.

```
import scrapy
#from ..items import ReviewItem

class TripAdvisorReview(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = "tripadvisor"
    start_urls = ["https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotels-g186217-England-Hotels.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("div.listing_title a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

    def parse_hotel(self, response):
        for info in response.css('div.page'):
            hotel_names = info.css('._1mTlpMC3::text').extract()
            hotel_names = [hotel_name.strip() for hotel_name in hotel_names]
            
            reviewer_names = info.css('._1r_My98y::text').extract()
            reviewer_names = [reviewer_name.strip() for reviewer_name in reviewer_names]
            reviewer_contributions = info.css('._3fPsSAYi:nth-child(1) ._1fk70GUn , ._1TuWwpYf+ ._3fPsSAYi ._1fk70GUn').css('::text').extract()
            reviewer_contributions = [reviewer_contribution.strip() for reviewer_contribution in reviewer_contributions]
            review_dates = info.xpath('//div[@class = "_2fxQ4TOx"]/span[contains(text(),"wrote a review")]/text()').extract()
            review_dates = [review_date.strip() for review_date in review_dates]
            review_stars = info.css('div.nf9vGX55 .ui_bubble_rating').xpath("@class").extract()
            review_stars = [review_star.strip() for review_star in review_stars]
            review_texts = info.css('#component_15 .cPQsENeY').css('::text').extract()
            review_texts = [review_text.strip() for review_text in review_texts]
            #helpful_vote = info.css('._3kbymg8R::text').extract()

            print('hotel_names:', len(hotel_names))
            print('reviewer_names:', len(reviewer_names))
            print('review_dates:', len(review_dates))
            print('review_stars:', len(review_stars))
            print('review_texts:', len(review_texts))
            print('reviewer_contributions:', len(reviewer_contributions))
            print('----')
            
            # without `hotel_names`
            all_reviews = zip(reviewer_names, review_dates, review_texts, review_stars, reviewer_contributions)

            hotel_name = hotel_names[0]  # <-- manually get first hotel

            # without `hotel_name`
            for reviewer_name, review_date, review_text, review_star, reviewer_contribution in all_reviews:
                #items = ReviewItem()
                items = dict()
                items['hotel_name'] = hotel_name  # <-- manually add first hotel
                items['reviewer_name'] = reviewer_name
                items['reviewer_contribution'] = reviewer_contribution
                items['review_date'] = review_date
                items['review_star'] = review_star
                items['review_text'] = review_text
                #items['helpful_vote'] = helpful_vote
                yield items
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(TripAdvisorReview)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:**

My version without `zip()`

First I search all `reviews` and later I use `for`-loop to work with every review separatelly. This way I can control `text` and skip `...` - simply I get only first `text` in `review`.

```
import scrapy
#from ..items import ReviewItem

class TripAdvisorReview(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = "tripadvisor"
    start_urls = ["https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotels-g186217-England-Hotels.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("div.listing_title a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

    def parse_hotel(self, response):
        hotel_name = response.css('#HEADING::text').extract_first().strip()
        print('hotel_name:', hotel_name)
        
        for review in response.xpath('.//div[@data-test-target="HR_CC_CARD"]'):
            name = review.css('._1r_My98y::text').extract_first().strip()
            contribution = review.css('._3fPsSAYi:nth-child(1) ._1fk70GUn , ._1TuWwpYf+ ._3fPsSAYi ._1fk70GUn').css('::text').extract_first().strip()
            date = review.xpath('.//div[@class="_2fxQ4TOx"]/span[contains(text(),"wrote a review")]/text()').extract_first().strip().replace('wrote a review ', '')
            stars = review.css('div.nf9vGX55 .ui_bubble_rating').xpath("@class").extract_first().strip().replace('ui_bubble_rating bubble_', '')
            text = review.xpath('.//div[@class="cPQsENeY"]//span/text()').extract_first().strip()

            #items = ReviewItem()
            items = dict()
            items['hotel_name'] = hotel_name  # <-- manually add first hotel
            items['reviewer_name'] = name
            items['reviewer_contribution'] = contribution
            items['review_date'] = date
            items['review_star'] = stars
            items['review_text'] = text

            yield items
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(TripAdvisorReview)
c.start()
```

Comment: Tested it and it works! Thank you so much. I'm new with Python and Scrapy and your comments add many learning points for me. Cheers!